# extjs3.4: How to use store filter on a grid

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, store, extjs3

I am using ExtJS3.4. 
I want to filter the `billingstore` based on value selected by the user for `billingName`.
So, How do I pass the value selected to the store or grid? How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
// Store for the grid panel - has billing grid data     
        this.billingStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                autoLoad: {params:{start: 0, limit: 2}},
                filter: {billingName}
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    url: '/ELCM/Client/getBillingList.do',
                }),
                root: 'data',
                fields: ['billingName','billingAmount','usedData','duration'],
                totalProperty:'totalRows'
        });
        var billingStore = this.billingStore;

    //view billing
        this.billingGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    title: 'View Billing',
                    store: that.billingStore,
                    columns:[
                          {header: "Amount",dataIndex: 'billingAmount'},
                           {header: "Data Used", dataIndex: 'usedData'},
                           {header: "Duration", dataIndex: 'duration'}
                         ],
                    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),
                    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                           store: that.billingStore,       // grid and PagingToolbar using same store
                           displayInfo: true,
                           pageSize: 2
                        }),
                     listeners: {
                                rowclick : function(grid, rowIndex, e){
                                 console.log("row Index "+rowIndex);
                                 }
                      }
        }); 
        var billingGrid = this.billingGrid;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to filter by a simple filter method on the store will achieve what your looking for.

```
billingGrid.getStore().filter([{
            property: '',
            id: '',
            value: 
        }
]);
```

Look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter for further information.

Comment: Can u please tel how I should send the value selected by the user?

Comment: If the user is selecting a value from the grid you will need a listener attached to your grid and then pass the value from the listener to the filter method above. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick

Comment: No, in my case the user will be selecting a row from the grid which has `billingname`, and then I need to open a new grid with details specific to the selected `billingname`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code ,how does the filter in ExtJS work its required the **property** (i.e billingName for filtering as per your example) then **'value'** on basis of which the filter happen this 2 are the mandatory options required for the filter function to work other optional config property which is **exactMatch** & **caseSensitive** which add the accuracy to the filter function.

Try out the below code

```
// Store for the grid panel - has billing grid data     
this.billingStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad: {params:{start: 0, limit: 2}},
            filter: [{
                    property: 'billingName', 
                    value: ''//Data source which need to be filter or based on value selected by the user for billingName
                    exactMatch: true,
                    caseSensitive: true
                }],
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: '/ELCM/Client/getBillingList.do',
            }),
            root: 'data',
            fields: ['billingName','billingAmount','usedData','duration'],
            totalProperty:'totalRows'
    });

var billingStore = this.billingStore;

//view billing
    this.billingGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                title: 'View Billing',
                store: that.billingStore,
                columns:[
                      {header: "Amount",dataIndex: 'billingAmount'},
                       {header: "Data Used", dataIndex: 'usedData'},
                       {header: "Duration", dataIndex: 'duration'}
                     ],
                sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),
                bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                       store: that.billingStore,       // grid and PagingToolbar using same store
                       displayInfo: true,
                       pageSize: 2
                    }),
                 listeners: {
                            rowclick : function(grid, rowIndex, e){
                             console.log("row Index "+rowIndex);
                             }
                  }
    }); 
    var billingGrid = this.billingGrid;
```